# How can I solve this detachedcriteria issue?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have this enum:

```
enum CompanyType {
    RESTAURANT('R'),
    BAR('B'),
    NIGHT_CLUB('N')

    final String id

    CompanyType(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    public Boolean isRestaurant() {
        this == RESTAURANT
    }

    public Boolean isBar() {
        this == BAR
    }

    public Boolean isNightClub() {
        this == NIGHT_CLUB
    }
}
```

And I have a domain like this:

```
class Company {
    String name
    String description
    CompanyType companyType
}
```

On my controller, when I try to list filtering by CompanyType, I do this:

```
companyList = Company.findAll(params,{companyType.id == selectedCompanyType.id})
```

And I get this error message:

```
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.companyType() is applicable for argument types: (com.memobile.where2go.CompanyController$_tt__index_closure9_closure15) values: [com.memobile.where2go.CompanyController$_tt__index_closure9_closure15@483c17c1]
```

If I put just companyType == selectedCompanyType I get an empty list...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 'where' query:

```
def companyList = Company.where {
    companyType == selectedCompanyType
}.list(params)
```